# two variables pattern check at once

Tags: bash, regular-expression, variable, test

Is it possible to check if two variables match regex pattern at once and not one by one?
Here is how it works now:

```
# A=1.1
# B=1.2
# [[ $A =~ ^([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?))?)$ && $B =~ ^([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?))?)$ ]] && echo A:$A B$B
A:1.1 B1.2
# B=1.2.3
# [[ $A =~ ^([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?))?)$ && $B =~ ^([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?))?)$ ]] && echo A:$A B$B
A:1.1 B1.2.3
# B=1.2.3.4
# [[ $A =~ ^([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?))?)$ && $B =~ ^([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?))?)$ ]] && echo A:$A B$B
#
```

I'd like to test both at once, like in this not-working test:

```
# [[ ($A|$B) =~ ^([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?))?)$ ]] && echo A:$A B$B
-bash: unexpected token `|', conditional binary operator expected
-bash: expected `)'
-bash: syntax error near `|$'
#
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't unfortunately do that (like that).  The left hand side of the `=~` operator in `bash` is a string (and should probably be quoted properly too).  If you want to, your could obviously craft a regular expression to match both strings at once (the concatenation of the two strings, or something), but that would make the code even harder to read and maintain and you would probably not gain any *speed* from it (if that's what you're after).

Also, when you test two things with `&&` in-between, consider using `[[ ... ]] && [[ ... ]]` rather than `[[ ... && ... ]]`, to be unambiguous and clear about what's included in the right hand side of the first test and what makes up the left hand side of the second test.

Comment: The LHS actually does not need quoting in `[[`, which has special parser semantics. For example: `foo='* foo * bar *'; [[ $foo == '* foo * bar *' ]]; echo $?`

Comment: @ChrisDown What about the `($A|$B)` that throws an error in the OP's question?

Comment: Ah, sure -- that's a syntactic misstep altogether rather than a quoting issue :-)

Comment: @ChrisDown Depends on how you see it. The OP could well use `"($A|$B)"` and then write a regular expression to match that...

Answer (score 0):

If there is a character you know can't appear in a successful match, you can check the concatenation of `$A` and `$B` against an appropriate duplicated regex.

```
regex='([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?))?)'

[[ "$A-$B" =~ ^$regex-$regex$ ]] && echo "A: $A B: $B"
```

You may need to adjust the regular expression slightly to compensate for it no longer containing `^` and `$` itself.